# Count number of times an element is repeated in a dictionary and keep one copy of it in another dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
{'Direcciones': [{'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}, {'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}, {'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'},{'Direccion': ' calle cualquiera', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}]}
```

As you can see, I have a list of dictionaries inside the key of 'Direcciones'

I am trying to count every time an object is repeated, delete the repetition, and add 1 to the original object.
For example, the output for this case shoyld be:

```
{'Direcciones': [{'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 3, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'},{'Direccion': ' calle cualquiera', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}]}
```

I am trying with while loops and del but I am mixing things up, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
dict =  {'Direcciones': [{'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}, {'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}, {'Direccion': ' calle miguel angel 11 4a planta', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'},{'Direccion': ' calle cualquiera', 'Apariciones': 1, 'CP': '28010', 'Ciudad': 'madrid'}]}
diccionario_temporal = dict.copy()
i=0
j=0
while i <= len(dict['Direcciones'])-1:
    while j <= len(diccionario_temporal['Direcciones'])-1:
        print(j,len(diccionario_temporal['Direcciones']))
        print(i,j)
        if i!=j:
            if dict['Direcciones'][i] == diccionario_temporal['Direcciones'][j]:
                print('VALIDA')
                print(i,j)
                dict['Direcciones'][i]['Apariciones'] = dict['Direcciones'][i]['Apariciones'] + 1
                del diccionario_temporal['Direcciones'][j]
                print('ONE DELETED')
                print(diccionario_temporal)
                j = j + 1
        else:
            j=j+1
            pass
    i=i+1
```

One problem I am having is that

```
dict['Direcciones'][i]['Apariciones'] = dict['Direcciones'][i]['Apariciones'] + 1
```

Also adds a number to the diccionario_temporal dictionary! I use .copy() so I do not know whats happening

Thanks

Comment: I think you should not do `j = j + 1` when the item is deleted because then you'll skip  element in your list: suppose you delete element at index 1 then the element that was at index 2 before deletion is not tested.

Comment: Also it seems strange that you never reinitialise `j` in your main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is almost always easier and more performant to filter and build a new list from scratch than to repeatedly remove elements. Using some utils, you can do, for instance:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

dirs = data["Direcciones"]  # just to make it more readable

# a key function that puts duplicates consecutively so they can 
# easily be grouped
key = itemgetter(*dirs[0].keys())  

dirs = [
    {**next(g), 'Apariciones': 1+len(list(g))} 
    for _, g in groupby(sorted(dirs, key=key), key=key)
]
```

This sorts the dicts and groups them into groups of duplicates (the lazy iterators `g`). Then the comprehension picks the first from the group and overrides the `'Apariciones'` key with `1` plus the length of the remainder of the group.